# How to render a specific page using my template mypage.html.twig?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to render a specific page using my own template. My theme regulating html.html.twig and page.html.twig. I want to rebuild completely the page.html.twig but only on specific page.

In my module based on `ControllerBase` I can only change the content of the page. How can I change the entire page template, but do not touch html theme wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable theme debug in the `services.yml` file:

```
#twig.config:
# debug: true
```

Clear the cache and reload the page, and you will see comments suggesting you to customize the template for each page you want.

[image]

Create a file in my theme.